# Sequential entry is not properly enter in database(MongoDB) under for loop Condition for various objects

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have an Array, under this, there are multiple objects
Example:

```
var array = [
              {'key': 'key4', 'value': 'value4'},
              {'key': 'key3', 'value': 'value3'},
              {'key': 'key2', 'value': 'value2'},
              {'key': 'key1', 'value': 'value1'}
             ];
```

My custom Function is like this:

```
var updateOnCollection = function(primaryfilter, secondaryfilter){
        Test.update(primaryfilter, {$push: secondaryfilter}, function(error2, result){
            if (error2) {
                logger.log('error', 'Error');
                console.log(error2);
            } else {
                console.log(result);  
            }
        });
    };
```

I have a Custom Function for an update. so just pass the key and value.
So when I was trying to update the query, Query is not done in a sequential manner. I am trying to run update query under for loop

```
for(var i = 0; i< array.length; i++){
    //My Custom Function
    //Value.updater(array[i].key, array[i].value);
   var primaryfilter = {'id': 1};
   var secondaryfilter = {'Elementname' : {'key': array[i].name, 'value':array[i].value }};
   updateOnCollection(primaryfilter, secondaryfilter);
}
```

But values is stored on db like this

```
{'key': 'key3', 'value': 'value3'},
 {'key': 'key4', 'value': 'value4'},
 {'key': 'key2', 'value': 'value2'},
 {'key': 'key1', 'value': 'value1'}
```

or some time like this

```
{'key': 'key4', 'value': 'value4'},
{'key': 'key2', 'value': 'value2'},
{'key': 'key3', 'value': 'value3'},
{'key': 'key1', 'value': 'value1'}
```

I know that this is happening due to some reason of loop. Anyone have better option to tackle these kinds of situation

Comment: Is `Value.updater()` asynchronous? If it is, even if the calls are sequential, it's not guaranteed that the they would be finished sequentially. What you can do is wait for each call to finish before proceeding with the next call.

Answer (score 0):

Use `await`. (This will work only for Node.js 7.6+)

```js
var updateOnCollection = async function(primaryfilter, secondaryfilter){
    try { 
        // Test.update() should return promise
        // Normally, Node.js db adapters return promise.
        await Test.update(primaryfilter, {$push: secondaryfilter});
    }
    catch(err) {
        logger.log('error', 'Error');
        console.log(error2);
    }
    return Promise.resolve();
}
```

In your `loop`

```js
for(var i = 0; i< array.length; i++){
      //My Custom Function
      //Value.updater(array[i].key, array[i].value);
      var primaryfilter = {'id': 1};
      var secondaryfilter = {'Elementname' : {'key': array[i].name, 'value':array[i].value }};
      await updateOnCollection(primaryfilter, secondaryfilter);
  }
```

Add `async` prefix to the `function`that executes above `loop`.

Comment: my function is : var updateOnCollection = function(primaryfilter, secondaryfilter){
    Test.update(primaryfilter, {$push: secondaryfilter}, function(error2, result){
        if (error2) {
            logger.log('error', 'Error ');
            console.log(error2);
        } else {
            console.log(result);  
        }
    });
};

Comment: I edited the question. Please go through my Function

Comment: I am using 6.11.4 LTS version. What was the concept for solving this? I mean this piece of code was not worked for me

Comment: @Iron_Man This will work Node.js 7.6+. await forces the process of the code until the promise is resolved. If you are not going to upgrade your node version, you can use node-q  - https://github.com/kriskowal/q